# Add together all objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like the next example:

```
let tryout = [
  {text: 1, video: 1, photo: 2, song: 1},
  {text: 2, video: 3, photo: 1},
  {text: 4, video: 2, photo: 2},
]
```

And I want to add them to get this kind of object at the end:

```
let newObjet = {
  text: 7,
  video: 6,
  photo: 5,
  song: 1
}
```

What would be the best way to do this. I am trying with `reduce()` but all I am getting is a merging of objects `keys`, and the `values` are not adding up.

One important thing is that I don't know what `keys` are gonna be inside of objects.

This is my attempt (not working as expected):

```
var resultObject = tryout.reduce(function(result, currentObject)
{
    for (var key in currentObject)
    {
        if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = currentObject[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is one way to achieve that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum values of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480773/sum-values-of-objects-in-array)

Comment: If it doesn't work, include a [mcve] of your best effort.

Comment: You should show the code you tried so we can show you where you are having trouble. This is definitely a case for reduce though.

Comment: I added my attempt. I don't really like a code on that Sum values of objects array because I dont know what keys I am gonna have in objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in combination with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let tryout = [
  {text: 1, video: 1, photo: 2, song: 1},
  {text: 2, video: 3, photo: 1},
  {text: 4, video: 2, photo: 2}
]

let res = tryout.reduce((acc, obj) =>
{
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) =>
    {
        acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + v;
    });

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

In relation to your code, you have an issue on the `if` sentence, instead of checking next condition:

```
if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...}
```

That will be `true` every time, the way you are using it (inside a loop that traverses the same object), you need to check if `result.hasOwnProperty(key)` in order to decide if adds the number to the previous stored result for that `key` or to assign it to the `key`.

```js
let tryout = [
  {text: 1, video: 1, photo: 2, song: 1},
  {text: 2, video: 3, photo: 1},
  {text: 4, video: 2, photo: 2}
]

var resultObject = tryout.reduce(function(result, currentObject)
{
    for (var key in currentObject)
    {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key))
            result[key] += currentObject[key];
        else
            result[key] = currentObject[key];
    }

    return result;
}, {});

console.log(resultObject);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```