# How to Solve this code in javascript? Combining of different objects with same value into single array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

Input

```
var arr = 
[
  [ 
    Packet { status: 'Apple', count: '2' },
    Packet { status: 'Lion', count: '2' }
   ],
  [
    Packet { status: 'Donkey', count: '2' },
    Packet { status: 'Apple', count: '2' },
    Packet { status: 'Cat', count: '1' }
  ],
  [
    Packet { status: 'Apple', count: '4' },
    Packet { status: 'Cat', count: '2' }
  ]
]
```

And I need  Output as

```
arr =
 [
    Packet { status: 'Donkey', count: '2' },
    Packet { status: 'Apple', count: '8' },
    Packet { status: 'Cat', count: '3' },
    Packet { status: 'Lion', count: '2' }
  ]
```

How can solve this??
Got Stuck in this for a week ?? ................................................................................................

Comment: You could use `arr.reduce`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480773/sum-values-of-objects-in-array)

Comment: syntax error on `Packet {  ...`

Comment: @MisterJojo I would assume `Packet` is the name of the class of those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and take `Object.values` of the object:

```js
const arr = [[{ status: 'Apple', count: '2' }, { status: 'Lion', count: '2' }], [{ status: 'Donkey', count: '2' }, { status: 'Apple', count: '2' }, { status: 'Cat', count: '1' }], [{ status: 'Apple', count: '4' }, { status: 'Cat', count: '2' }]];

const result = Object.values(arr.flat().reduce((a,
    { status, count }) => ((a[status] ??= { status, count: 0 }).count += +count,
        a), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: your `count`s are not of string type, as OP question is.

Answer (score 0):

simply that:

```js
var arr = 
    [ [ { status: 'Apple',  count: '2' } 
      , { status: 'Lion',   count: '2' } 
      ] 
    , [ { status: 'Donkey', count: '2' } 
      , { status: 'Apple',  count: '2' } 
      , { status: 'Cat',    count: '1' } 
      ] 
    , [ { status: 'Apple',  count: '4' } 
      , { status: 'Cat',   count: '2' } 
      ] 
    ] 

var arr2 = arr.flat().reduce((a,c)=>
    {
    let item = a.find(x=>x.status===c.status)
    if (!item)  a.push({...c})
    else item.count = (eval(`${item.count} + ${c.count}`)).toString(10)
    return a
    },[])

console.log( arr2 )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Almost there. The count of `Apple` should be `8` and `Cat` should be `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Arrady#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to sum them up. Also used are `+` prefix to convert string to number and spread operator to modify the object partially.

```js
let arr = [ [ { status: 'Apple', count: '2' }, { status: 'Lion', count: '2' } ], [ { status: 'Donkey', count: '2' }, { status: 'Apple', count: '2' }, { status: 'Cat', count: '1' } ], [ { status: 'Apple', count: '4' }, { status: 'Cat', count: '2' } ] ];

let output = arr.flat().reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const i = acc.findIndex(item => item.status === curr.status);
  if (i !== -1) acc[i]['count'] += +curr['count'];
  else acc.push({...curr, count: +curr['count']});
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```