# Combine an object of array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[image: Object]

I have an Object of Arrays like this and I want to combine them(add values  to every key )

It's possible to give to every array key: "state" and value: parseFloat(value) or how i can do it?

Comment: Use for loop or reduce to add up the values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480773/sum-values-of-objects-in-array)

Comment: Isn't the title should be an array of objects?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the expected output and the attempt(s) you made of solving the problem? This way we can help you understand the issue better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save yourself some typing, and provide some future-proofing in case you later need to handle a different set of territories, by getting the keys from the object itself, and then iterating over those keys:

```
let val = {};
val = filteredMiles.reduce(
    function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        const keys=Object.keys(previousValue);
        const result={};
        keys.forEach(key=>{
            result[key]= parseFloat(previousValue[key])) 
                        +parseFloat(currentvalue[key])
        })
        return result
    };
 });
console.log(val);
```