# How to get an object containing the sum of all items in an arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects where each index is one week where I bought groceries. Meaning that array[0] is the first week, array[1] is the second and the so on. What I need to do is do sum all the values of the same items using Underscore (not for loop, or while). Here is one example:

```
   console.log(weeklyGroceries([
                                  {
                                    apple: 1,
                                    banana: 4,
                                    fish: 2,
                                    melon: 3,
                                  },
                                  {
                                    apple: 3,
                                    banana: 2,
                                    fish: 5,
                                    melon: 1,
                                  }
                                ]));
```

It should print:

```
{
apple: 4,
banana: 6,
fish: 27,
melon: 4
}
```

Any ideas?

I have tried using reduce to get all the values, but I still have to sum the same values it wouldn't be in object form anymore.

```
var keys = array.reduce((value,obj) => [...value, ...Object.values(obj)],[]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480773/sum-values-of-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` is the very good idea. I guess you were misleaded a bit by `reduce` signature Consider following:

`reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { /* … */ })`

It means, that reduce will work on each iteration with some kind of `accumulator` (this will carry on sum on each loop iteration) and current value of array, one after another on each iteration.

```
weeklyGroceries.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
 return {
   apple: acc.apple + currentValue.apple,
   banana: acc.banana + currentValue.banana,
   fish: acc.fish + currentValue.fish,
   melon: acc.melon + currentValue.melon,
  }
}, {
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  fish: 0,
  melon: 0,
})
```

If, for some reason, like training or just for fun, you wish to avoid using build-in functions, you can achieve same, by manually iterating over every entry of your object and sum all respective fields:

```
let sums = {};
Object.keys(weeklyGroceries[0]).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key)
  let partailSum = 0;
  for (let idx = 0; idx < weeklyGroceries.length; idx++) {
    partailSum += weeklyGroceries[idx][key];
  }
  sums[key] = partailSum;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_.reduce` function from the Underscore library to sum the values of the same items in the array of objects.

Here is an example:

```
function weeklyGroceries(weeks) {
  return _.reduce(weeks, function(result, week) {
    _.each(week, function(value, key) {
      result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + value;
    });
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun exercise in functional programming. Assuming you already have a `sum` function for simple arrays of numbers, you can implement `weeklyGroceries` in just two expressions. No loops, anonymous functions or `if`/`else` required:

```js
var add = (a, b) => a + b;
var sum = _.partial(_.reduce, _, add, 0);

function weeklyGroceries(groceriesByDay) {
    var keys = _.chain(groceriesByDay)
    .map(_.keys).flatten().uniq().value();
    return _.chain(keys).zip(keys).object()
    .mapObject(_.property)
    .mapObject(_.partial(_.map, groceriesByDay))
    .mapObject(_.compose(sum, _.compact))
    .value();
}

console.log(weeklyGroceries([{
    apple: 1,
    banana: 4,
    fish: 2,
    melon: 3,
}, {
    apple: 3,
    banana: 2,
    fish: 5,
    melon: 1,
}]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

While the implementation of `weeklyGroceries` is not straightforward, figuring out how it works will deepen your understanding of functional programming. This will empower you to write some things very concisely, such as the definition of `sum` at the top.

For the convenience of the reader, here are links to the documentation of each Underscore function used in this snippet, by order of evaluation:

[`_.partial`](https://underscorejs.org/#partial)
[`_.reduce`](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce)
[`_.chain`](https://underscorejs.org/#chain)
[`_.map`](https://underscorejs.org/#map)
[`_.keys`](https://underscorejs.org/#keys)
[`_.flatten`](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten)
[`_.uniq`](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq)
[`_.value`](https://underscorejs.org/#value)
[`_.zip`](https://underscorejs.org/#zip)
[`_.object`](https://underscorejs.org/#object)
[`_.mapObject`](https://underscorejs.org/#mapObject)
[`_.property`](https://underscorejs.org/#property)
[`_.partial`](https://underscorejs.org/#partial)
[`_.compose`](https://underscorejs.org/#compose)
[`_.compact`](https://underscorejs.org/#compact)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pure js:

```
function weeklyGroceries(arr) {
  
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    for (const key in curr) {
      if(acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = acc[key] + curr[key];
      } else {
        acc[key] = curr[key];
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could upvote!